# Bootstrap datepicker not working with AJAX load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I have an AJAX loaded page - `users.php`. Every time I click on the users tab, the following function is called:

```
function users(){
    var id = document.getElementById("usersstab");
    $("#users").load("load.php");
    $("#users").load("users.php");
}
```

In users.php, I have a form that is hidden. The form is displayed only on the click of "Add user" button. In that form, I have a birth date field, for which I want to use the `datepicker()`.

```
<input id="dobofsubuser" type="text" name="subuserdob" class="form-control" />
```

I call this function at the footer of the main (parent page) :

```
$('#dobofsubuser').datepicker({
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    endDate: "Current Date",
    startView: 2
});
```

This doesn't show the calendar and I have tried to look for answers but none of the previously mentioned solutions have helped this far. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong or what needs to be done so that the datepicker works on `load()` ? Thanks in advance!

This is the order of my scripts:

```
        <script src="js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="js/validetta.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/sweet-alert.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
```

If there is no solution here, can someone please suggest an alternative calendar plugin that would work well with ajax loaded pages?

Answer (score 0):

Try to init your `datepicker` after load :

```
$("#users").load("users.php", function() {
    $('#dobofsubuser').datepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        endDate: "Current Date",
        startView: 2
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How can i do that? I tried calling datepicker() at the end of users(). That didn't work!

Comment: Yeah this is the error -> $(...).datepicker is not a function

Comment: Make sure that your jquery not loaded twice.

Comment: Have you included the bootstrap js file in your html? 
Are you calling it before initiating the datepicker component?

Comment: it seems like you include jquery in line 2 and fifth line also, try to eliminate one of them.

Comment: One is plain jquery and one more is for AJAX. If I remove either one of them, the pages won't load.

Comment: Try to replace the both by the following one `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js`.

Comment: One jquery import in top should work for ajax and all other plugins and that will fix the problem of dfatepicke but i'm not sure why the last link not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Possibly there is some js library that is interfering with your code.

Try this for bootstrap datepicker

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var datepicker = $.fn.datepicker.noConflict();
    $.fn.bootstrapDP = datepicker;  
    $("#datepicker").bootstrapDP({  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});  
});
```